# Unable to display 2 markers on google maps in objective C ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm unable to display two markers on the google maps in objective C. I'm trying to pass two values to it. I realise it might just be getting overwritten but I haven't been able to fix it yet. Please help. 
Here's my code from .m file:

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(toLatitudeDouble, toLongitudeDouble);
marker.title=toLocationFromResultVC;
marker.snippet=@"Destination";



marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(fromLatitudeDouble, fromLongitudeDouble);
marker.title=fromLocationFromResultVC;
marker.snippet=@"Source";

marker.map = mapView_;
```

Do I need to provide any more details?
I'd be glad for any help I can get.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you're overriding the value. You should create another marker instead.

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(toLatitudeDouble, toLongitudeDouble);
marker.title=toLocationFromResultVC; marker.snippet=@"Destination";

// Your're overriding the value here!!
// use GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init]; and reference it instead in the code below.

marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(fromLatitudeDouble, fromLongitudeDouble); 
marker.title=fromLocationFromResultVC; marker.snippet=@"Source";

marker.map = mapView_;
```

So, the correct code would be

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(toLatitudeDouble, toLongitudeDouble);
marker.title=toLocationFromResultVC; marker.snippet=@"Destination";
marker.map = mapView_;

GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker2.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(fromLatitudeDouble, fromLongitudeDouble); 
marker2.title=fromLocationFromResultVC; marker.snippet=@"Source";
marker2.map = mapView_;
```